# USB-host on PIC32: enumeration not working

Tags: pic, mplabx, usb-host

I've been struggling with this problem for about half a year and I'm on the verge giving up completely. This post on this forum is my last resort, and I hope anyone can throw some light on what I'm doing wrong.

Facts: PIC32MM0128GPM048 on an own developed PCB with the goal to read a USB keyboard just to get the hang of how USB host works.

Using Microchip Code Configurator in MPLABX I've setup everything required for USB host and let it create the code. Then I copied the code from USB HID examples in MLA (Microchip Library for Applications). In short; a far from a blinking LED, I haven't typed a single line of code. Everything comes from Microchip.

Using MCC, I've also generated code for UART2 (with printf to UART checked) and USB-host. In the USB-code, there's a lot of DEBUG-lines from Microchip which are called if DEBUG_ENABLE is enabled. So, I enabled all the DEBUG-outputs just to investigate what's happening. I connected a PL2303 USB-TTL-adapter for the debugging. I've checked "HID Keyboard" in MCC under the USB TPL-table settings.

I program the chip and put it in run-mode, and I can see this in the serial-window:

```
HOST: Initializing DETACHED state.
```

So, the USB-stack is initialized and the PIC is running. Then I connect a keyboard and see this:

```
[>HOST: Starting settling delay.
```

Then there's...nothing in the serial-window, and I'm unsure where to go from here. Trying to pinout the error, I flooded the USB-code with more debug-messages and I finally found where the code gets stuck:

```
                    case SUBSUBSTATE_WAIT_FOR_SETTLING:
                        // Wait for the timer to finish in the background.
                        LED_Toggle();
                        break;
```

So it seems that the USB-connection is never settling. Now I just have to find out what that means, and this is what I've been trying to figure out for half a year without succeeding.

Reading the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC32MM0256GPM064-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001387D.pdf) again I find that to be able to use USB host the clock source is crucial, no more than +-50ppm drift is allowed. At first I missed this information so I assumed my HC49 crystal was the culprit, so I switched it to a MEMS-oscillator. Same result.

Then I double triple checked in case it was a PCB error, that the crystal clock lines were interfering the USB data lines or similiar, but they are way apart (see image where I've marked up the two pairs of connections) so I do not think this is the source of error. I could ofcourse be wrong.

I'm out of options. I have no more ideas of where the error source can be. I cannot isolate it to a software error or a hardware error.

Any ideas, help or pointers that will get me forward on this project would be immensely appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the keyboard gets enough stable power? The supply and ground wires are as thin as any other wire you have there. Also is the pinout of the USB connector correct, I mean are the GND, VCC, D+ and D- on correct pins? It is impossible to see without schematics. The D+ and D- pins to the MCU should be a high speed differential pair, currently it is routed against all suggested rules for high speed differential pairs.

Comment: @Justme thanks for the input. I will scope the USB power line to see if Vcc is stable. It is also possible I have made a mistake with switching place of D+ / D-, I will double check this. Regarding the routing I can probably not fix that on this PCB prototype, but I will certainly read up about it.

Comment: I have now double checked the PCB, and the D+ / D- are connected correctly. However, I think I've found a mistake. USB pin 1 (Vcc) is connected directly to my +5V power source, but I recall now that the datasheet says that for USB Host the PIC32 is supposed to control the power line. This is not done. I will have to read up more what and where I should connect USB pin 1 so the PIC32 can control it.